# Validation with Spring 3.2.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, spring-3, hibernate-validator

I'm using [HibernateValidator 4.3.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/4.3.1.Final/). Validations are performed as intended throughout the entire application.

I have registered some custom editors to perform validation globally such as for ensuring numeric values (`double`, `int` etc) in a text-field, for ensuring valid dates regarding the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) API etc.

In this type of validation, I'm allowing null/empty values by setting the `allowEmpty` parameter to `false` as usual to validate it separately especially for displaying separate user friendly error messages when such fields are left blank.

Therefore, in addition to validating with HibernateValidator and custom editors, I'm trying to use the following validation strategy. Again, this kind of validation is only for those fields which are registered for custom editors **are when left blank**.

The following is the class that implements the [`org.springframework.validation.Validator`](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) interface.

```
package test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import validatorbeans.TempBean;

@Component
public final class TempValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        System.out.println("supports() invoked.");
        return TempBean.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        TempBean tempBean = (TempBean) target;

        System.out.println("startDate = " + tempBean.getStartDate() + " validate() invoked.");
        System.out.println("doubleValue = " + tempBean.getDoubleValue() + " validate() invoked.");
        System.out.println("stringValue = " + tempBean.getStringValue() + " validate() invoked.");

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "startDate", "java.util.date.nullOrEmpty.error");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "doubleValue", "java.lang.double.nullOrEmpty.error");
    }
}
```

The class is designated with the `@Component` annotation so that it can be auto-wired to a specific Spring controller class. The debugging statements display exactly based on the input provided by a user.

The following is the controller class.

```
package controller;

import customizeValidation.CustomizeValidation;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.groups.Default;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.DataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import test.TempValidator;
import validatorbeans.TempBean;

@Controller
public final class TempController {

    @Autowired
    private TempService tempService;

    private TempValidator tempValidator;

    public TempValidator getTempValidator() {
        return tempValidator;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setTempValidator(TempValidator tempValidator) {
        this.tempValidator = tempValidator;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, value = {"admin_side/Temp"})
    public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("tempBean") @Valid TempBean tempBean, BindingResult error, Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "admin_side/Temp";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, value = {"admin_side/Temp"})
    public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("tempBean") @Valid TempBean tempBean, BindingResult errors, Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        //tempValidator.supports(TempBean.class);
        //tempValidator.validate(tempBean, errors);

        DataBinder dataBinder = new DataBinder(tempBean);
        dataBinder.setValidator(tempValidator);
        dataBinder.validate();

        //errors=dataBinder.getBindingResult();
        if (CustomizeValidation.isValid(errors, tempBean, TempBean.ValidationGroup.class, Default.class) && !errors.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Validated");
        }

        return "admin_side/Temp";
    }
}
```

I'm invoking the validator from the Spring controller class itself (which I indeed want) by

```
DataBinder dataBinder = new DataBinder(tempBean);
dataBinder.setValidator(tempValidator);
dataBinder.validate();
```

The validator is called but the validation which is expected is **not** performed.

If only I invoke the validator manually using the following statement (which is commented out above),

```
tempValidator.validate(tempBean, errors);
```

then validation is performed. So I don't believe my validator is correctly working. Why does it fail to work with `DataBinder`?

In my `application-context.xml` file, this bean is simply configured as follows.

```
<bean id="tempValidator" class="test.TempValidator"/>
```

This many packages as below including the `test` package which the `TempValidator` class is enclosed within are auto-detected.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller spring.databinder validatorbeans validatorcommands test" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>  
</context:component-scan>
```

I have even tried to put

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

In my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: If you put a break on the line "dataBinder.validate();" and step into it, can you see which validator is being called eventually?

Comment: @CodeChimp - The validator invoked is the one specified in the question -`tempValidator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well what you try to achieve - distinguish between blank fields and incorrect values entered - you can use MUCH MORE SIMPLER approach:

```
public class MyBean {

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm") 
    private DateTime date;

    @NotNull
    @Max(value=5)
    private Integer max;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max=20)
    private String name;

    // getters, setters ... 
}
```

Controller mapping:

```
public void submitForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid MyBean myBean, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors){
       // do something}
    else{
       // do something else
    }        
}
```

Validation messages:

```
NotNull=Required field.
NotNull.date=Date is required field.
NotNull.max=Max is required field.
Size=Must be between {2} and {1} letters.
Max=Must be lower than {1}.
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=Must be number.
typeMismatch.org.joda.time.DateTime=Required format dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm
```

Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseValidatorConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {

        LocalValidatorFactoryBean lvfb = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        lvfb.setValidationMessageSource(getValidationMessageSource());
        return lvfb;
    }

    protected MessageSource getValidationMessageSource() {// return you validation messages ...}
}
```

I can provide more details and explanation, if needed.

Comment: Ah! I never used this `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`. Annotations like `@NotEmpty`, `@NotBlank`, `@NotNull` etc work on their own (in Spring 3.2.2 that I'm using currently). What is this `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` for? More over, `@Configuration` is better than XML configuration? Thank you.

Comment: `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` provides a bridge between Spring MVC Validator and JSR-303 Bean Validation implementation - it enables you for example to use `@Valid` annotation in controller methods which provides out-of-box validation errors binding to a binding result as shown in the example code) and also use validation messages in Spring's way (error codes message resolvers). `@Configuration` provides more flexibility and is less error prone but you can achieve same things in both java and XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the approach as mentioned in the question didn't work. I didn't make it work but walking through this [document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html), I found another approach that worked for me as per my requirements.

I set the validator inside a method which was designated by the `@InitBinder` annotation.

From [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-configuring)

> The Validator instance invoked when a @Valid method argument is
>   encountered may be configured in two ways. First, you may call
>   binder.setValidator(Validator) within a @Controller's @InitBinder
>   callback. This allows you to configure a Validator instance per
>   @Controller class:

Specifically, in my requirements, the validation should only be performed while updating or inserting data into the database i.e when an associated submit button for those operations is pressed (there is a common button for both of these tasks (insert and update) in my application whose name is `btnSubmit`).

The validation should be muted in any other case (for example, when the delete button is pressed). To meet this requirement, I have registered the validator as follows.

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest webRequest) {
    if (webRequest.getParameter("btnSubmit") != null) {
        binder.setValidator(new TempValidator());
    } else {
        binder.setValidator(null);
    }
}
```

In this situation, the validator - `TempValidator` would only be set when the submit button whose name attribute is `btnSubmit` is clicked by the client.

There is no need for xml configuration anywhere as well as auto-wiring.

The exemplary controller class now looks like the following.

```
@Controller
public final class TempController {

    @Autowired
    private TempService tempService;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest webRequest) {
        if (webRequest.getParameter("btnSubmit") != null) {
            binder.setValidator(new TempValidator());
        } else {
            binder.setValidator(null);
        }
    }

    //Removed the @Valid annotation before TempBean, since validation is unnecessary on page load.
    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, value = {"admin_side/Temp"})
    public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("tempBean") TempBean tempBean, BindingResult error, Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "admin_side/Temp";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, value = {"admin_side/Temp"})
    public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("tempBean") @Valid TempBean tempBean, BindingResult errors, Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (CustomizeValidation.isValid(errors, tempBean, TempBean.ValidationGroup.class, Default.class) && !errors.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("Validated");
        }
        return "admin_side/Temp";
    }
}
```

The `WebRequest` paramenter in the `initBinder()` method is not meant for handling the entire Http request as obvious. It's just for using general purpose request metadata.

Javadocs about `WebRequest`.

> Generic interface for a web request. Mainly intended for generic web
>   request interceptors, giving them access to general request metadata,
>   not for actual handling of the request.

If there is something wrong that I might be following, then kindly clarify it or add another answer.